# How long do I mix for the Beserk Potion?

Tags: candy-box-2

It says "until my hands hurt"? Is this a specific time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Candy Box 2 Wiki](http://wiki.candybox2.net/doku.php?id=berserk_potion)

> Mix them until your arms are hurting” is 60 seconds

Comment: It does specifically say that your arms hurt, too, so the game makes it pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

keep on mixing until the screen reads your hand hurts which is a minute